# How can I reset the cassandra journal between unit test?

Tags: cassandra, akka, cqrs, event-sourcing, akka-persistence

I am testing an actor system and I would like to handle the reset of the journal between test run.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use the cassandra journal in your tests?

I would strongly suggest you use the `in-memory` journal:

so in your test `application.confgi` you specify

```
akka {
  persistence {
    journal {
      plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.inmem"
    }
  }
}
```

and you get a fresh journal